# How to move an object in Unity/the scripts are not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to unity and I have searched up how to make something move, such as a player. I have tried about 5 different websites, one of them by unity itself, and they all don't do ANYTHING. I'm quite frustrated, and I do not know how to fix this can you please tell me what's wrong? It may be because I'm using an older Unity, or my Unity just sucks, but I'm not sure. The script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
}
```

Thank you, I hope I will find out why, and HOPEFULLY, it will actually work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question might not have enough details for someone to help you. It looks like a lot of the relevant code is missing. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: Speed is never assigned a value, so it defaults to zero.

Comment: Do you have this script attached to your player? Does your player have a rigidbody component attached? How are you inputting (e.g. keyboard?). Have you experimented with the settings on the rigidbody? Try resetting them to default. Try Vector3 movement = transform.position + new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

Comment: @MichaelRoy Oh yeah, guess I should have thought Occam's razor before my last comment :)

Comment: Speed is likely set in the editor ui of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. Some possible reasons you didn't achieve what you want:

- Your player does not have a RigiBody component;
- You have not attached the script to the player;
- You didn't assign a value to the speed variable in the inspector;
- You're inputting the wrong keys(Default "Horizontal" and "Vertical" keys are "w-a-s-d" and arrow keys).